Blazor UI not updating with StateHasChanged
I'm having difficult with getting my UI to automatically update, I've bound LifetimeService.Items to the table yet it's not updating when I call InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged).
I've tried everything I can think of such as IDisposible on LifetimeService, changing from List<Item> to OberservableCollection<Item> etc as well as cleaning and rebuilding my project.
I've double checked the Items list is populating correctly and it is. It works if I manually refresh the page. The timer is also working fine
Here is my table
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>ItemSlot</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in LifetimeService.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><img src="@item.Image" alt="Image" width="100" height="100" /></td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
                <td><a href="@item.Link">Link</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

I have a class LifetimeService containing Items List
public class LifetimeService
{
    public int ScanAmounts = 0;

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();

    public bool AddItem(Item item)
    {           
        if (Items.Any(x => x.Name == item.Name && x.Price == item.Price && x.Image == item.Image && x.Link == item.Link))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ScanAmounts == 0)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Items.Insert(0, item);
            return true;
        }
    }
}

I have my method running on a timer which grabs data then runs
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);.
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();  
    
    if (LifetimeService.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    StartTimer();
    await ScrapeData();
}

private void StartTimer()
{
    _timer = new Timer(async _ =>
       {
           await InvokeAsync(ScrapeData);
       }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}

private async Task ScrapeData()
{
   {
       {
...
        var added = LifetimeService.AddItem(new Item { Name = name, Price = price, Image = img, Link = link });
        if (added)
        {
            addedAnythingToList = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Title: " + title);
            Debug.WriteLine("Price: " + price);
            Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
            Debug.WriteLine("Image: " + img);                    
        }
    }

    if (addedAnythingToList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Invoking state has changed");
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        Debug.WriteLine("Finished Invoking");
    }

    // Close the browser
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine("Inner: " + ex.InnerException);

}
finally
{
    // Ensure the driver quits even if an exception occurs
    driver.Dispose();
    driver.Quit();
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chromedriver");
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("Time taken: " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    LifetimeService.ScanAmounts++;        
}
...


There are several issues with you code, so I've created a Minimal Reproducible Example based on it to demonstrate one way of implementing a timer to run the scraper.
The data and service.  I have used a record because it's simplifies equality checking.
namespace SO78687434;

public record Model(DateTime TimeStamp, string Name, decimal Price);

public class LifetimeService
{
    public int ScanAmounts = 0;

    // Should implement an ItemsProvider delegate if there is lots of data
    // And a Thread safe collection if the list is updated from different threads
    public List<Model> Items { get; private set; } = new();

    public bool AddItem(Model model)
    {
        if (Items.Any(item => item with { TimeStamp = model.TimeStamp} == model))
            return false;

        Items.Add(model);

        return true;
    }
}

And then the demo page.
This sets up the timer in OnInitialized.  The timer itself is managed by the [internal] Timer Service and the callback [in this case the scraper] is invoked on a threadpool thread.
Scheduling one off timers like this circumvents race conditions,  removes the need for thread locking.
@page "/"
@inject LifetimeService LifetimeService
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @* Ought to use the ItemsProvider if there is going to be lots of data *@
        <Virtualize TItem="Model" Items="this.LifetimeService.Items.OrderByDescending(item => item.TimeStamp).ToList()">
            <tr>
                <td>@context.Name</td>
                <td>@context.Price</td>
            </tr>
        </Virtualize>
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    private Timer? _timer;
    private Model _baseData = new(DateTime.Now, "Fred", 10);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // set up the initial timer one time event
        _timer = new(this.ScrapeDataAsync, null, 100, 0);

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private async void ScrapeDataAsync(object? data)
    {
        // Fake some async work
        await Task.Yield();

        // should only add on first pass
        this.LifetimeService.AddItem(_baseData);

        decimal price = _baseData.Price + 1;
        _baseData = _baseData with { TimeStamp= DateTime.Now, Name = $"Fred-{price}", Price = price };

        this.LifetimeService.AddItem(_baseData);

        // This is not a UI event so we need to manually call StateHasChanged
        // It will be run on the threadpool so we need to invoke it on the Synchronisation Context
        await this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);

        // schedules a new one time timer event 
        _timer = new(this.ScrapeDataAsync, null, 2000, 0);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}



I dropped my answer because the original had InvokeAsync(ScrapeData);. But the code here does have a data race, in principle. With a 1 minute tact it won't show.

@HenkHolterman -  I proposed my new version because I decided there were two many issues with the old code.  Do you think this ought to use a thread safe collection?  Used as is there's no problems because there's only ever one thread writing at a time.

It's safe but still a bit of an eye-sore. The OP wraps ScrapeDataAsync in InvokeAsync, that looks better. But then there's a nested InvokeAsync(), I wonder if that could block something.

async void ScrapDataAsync is better and more honest about what's happening. But you are missing an 'e' there.

Good point on ScrapeDataAsync in InvokeAsync, but then you're loading what is basically a background (potentially slow) process on the UI thread.  Fixed my typo!

Try With below code:
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
   {
       await base.OnParametersSetAsync();  
     
       
       if (LifetimeService.Items.Count > 0)
       {
           return;
       }
       StartTimer();
       await ScrapeData();
      StateHasChanged();
   }


Doesn't do anything different :/

It is never required to call StateHasChanged at the end of OnParametersSetAsync (or any other Task in Blazor really).
